# Pandas groupby agg - how to get counts?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to get sum, mean and count of a metric

```
df.groupby(['id', 'pushid']).agg({"sess_length": [ np.sum, np.mean, np.count]})
```

But I get "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'count'", and I have tried different ways of expressing the count function but can't get it to work. How do I just an aggregate record count together with the other metrics?

Comment: Do you just want `len`? Not sure what you mean about different ways of expressing the count function - `numpy` certainly doesn't have `np.count`, as you've seen. What is this function expected to do?

Comment: you can use `np.size`

Comment: @jxc `size` will count `nan` as a row, `count` will exclude `nan`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use strings instead of the functions, like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": list("ccdef"), "pushid": list("aabbc"), 
     "sess_length": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
)

df.groupby(["id", "pushid"]).agg({"sess_length": ["sum", "mean", "count"]})
```

Which outputs:

```
           sess_length
                   sum mean count
 id pushid
 c  a               30   15     2
 d  b               30   30     1
 e  b               40   40     1
 f  c               50   50     1
```

Answer (score 3):

just use `np.size`

Not sure why the answer needs to be 30 chars long, when the answer is straightforward

Comment: I was looking for that exactly. `np.count_nonzero` didn't look suitable.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'pushid']).agg({"sess_length": [ np.sum, np.mean, np.**size**]})
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to this syntax over the use of `[ 'sum', 'mean', 'count']`, as described in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599377/3025856) from last year? If so, it'd be useful to edit your answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean :

```
df.groupby(['id', 'pushid']).agg({"sess_length": [ 'sum', 'count','mean']})
```

As mentioned in [documentation of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), you can use string arguments like 'sum','count'.  TBH It's more preferable way of doing these aggregations.